# Jquery Mobile Horizontal Data-Type Triggers Vertical

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying to load a fieldset as shown on

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-rc.1/docs/forms/checkboxes/

with **data-type="horizontal"**

the code properly contains all the necessary information.  It works just fine on my frontpage.  However, when I **.trigger('create')** the list shows up as a vertical list, and ignores the data-type - when the content is dynamically loaded, then triggered.

I'm thinking this could be solved 1 of 2 ways.

1. Change the Default Radio Layout to Horizontal (Hard Code Jquery modification)
2. Somehow get .Trigger to work properly

I've tried **refresh** as well with no luck. and have seen others on here "Looking for hours" on here as well.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my own error by Double Checking my Code;
Rebuilding my Jqm Library with a more recent version (Fixed it);

running .trigger and assiging a specific div contrainer for it

eg.

$('#TARGET').trigger('create');

after the div is loaded